# What does "selling traffic" mean?

Tags: marketing, web-traffic

I've been told that a marketing team want to "sell the traffic" of a website rather than sell adverts on the site.  A Google wasn't very successful as to what this means.

I thought perhaps it just meant pop-unders (argh!), but wondered if anyone has a better definition of what it could mean.

Answer (score 2):

For me, selling traffic is applying 301 redirects from URLs of your site to URLs of the site for which you sell traffic. In this way, you give all your traffic to the other site.